# Individual comment box toggle for each tweet(like Twitter)?

Tags: jquery, css

I'm pretty new to jQuery and JS. I am trying to build something like Twitter albeit,of course, a simpler version. [Here's the JSFiddle:](http://jsfiddle.net/9cLfR/1/) Basically I want each different tweet to have its own comment box.(Note: A comment won't have a re-comment option; all comments will serially come under the root tweet) What's happening right now is that, for all (distinct) tweets, the comment box comes up at the end of the last tweet. How would I achieve what I'm trying to do?

**Javascript:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#btn1").click(function () {
    $("p").append(" <b>Appended text</b>.");
});

$(".commentbutton").click(function v() {
    var text = $("#txt1").val();

    $("body").append('<br><div class="x"><label class="gp">' + text + '</label><button id="b1"</button>Comment</div>');
    $("body").find(".x:last").hide().slideDown("slow");

});

$(document).on('click', '.x>button', function () {
    $('body').find('.x:last').append('<input id="txt1" type="text">');
    });
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<div style="position:absolute;left:230px;top:30px;border:solid;display:inline-block">
<p>Type a tweet</p>
<input id="txt1" type="text">
<br>
<button id="btn2" class="commentbutton">Tweet</button>
</div>
```

**The CSS:**

```
.gp {
border-style:solid;
max-width:30%;
padding:2px;
display:block;
}
.x {
width:200px;
background-color:#93bbd4;
border-style:solid;
}
#txt1 {
width:200px;
height:28px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this: [Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/9cLfR/5/)

```
$(document).on('click', '.x>button', function () {
    var id = "twt" + $(this).parent().index() +  "txt" + ($(this).parent().find('input').length+1);
    $(this).parent().append('<input id="' + id+ '" type="text">');
});
```

I have fixed the issue of textbox appendind . Besides that, I have also fixed the **multiple id** problem you are having..

Comment: Yes, that's better. I changed the append to prepend() .However, do this: Tweet something.Hit 'Comment'. And now again add another tweet. The newest tweet contents are not visible. Why is that so?

Comment: Awesome man! That's exactly what I wanted! I'm on a pretty tight project schedule and it's not at all easy having to learn CSS,JS,jQuery,Ajax(have to!) and Servlets! Then there are people like you on SO! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Change `append()` to `prepend()` . If I understood your question right, thats all you need.

Comment: No, that's not quite the effect I want. Doing a `prepend()` makes the tweet arrangement inverted.(The newer tweets go farther down the page). Also, I'd like the comments to appear beneath the original tweet(similar to FB). In this case, the comments all go up.